# Grouping Dictionary by value using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have a dictionary that stores strings as keys and ints as values that represent words and the number of times they occur. The user needs to be able to sort them by number of uses or alphabetically by 1st letter. I'd prefer to use LINQ although I am rather new to it. I have been able to group the words based on starting letter using the following code:

```
public string AlphabeticWordBuilder()
{
    List<String> words = this.myWords.WordsAsList();
    words.Sort();
    return GroupWords(words);
}

private static string GroupWords(List<String> words)
{
    String formatedWords = string.Empty;
    var groups =
        from w in words
        group w by w.First();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        formatedWords += ("\n" + group.Key + ":\n");
        foreach (var w in group)
        {
            formatedWords += (w);
        }
    }
    return formatedWords;
}
```

However this method requires me to convert the keys of my dictionary into a list causing me to lose my values. I should be able to group my dictionary by the value in a similar fashion but I do not know how to incorporate the key/value relationship into the code I am using for the alphabetic sorting. Can someone please post an example of using LINQ to group a dictionary by value?

Also I'd like to avoid the LINQ method syntax and continue to use the LINQ query expression syntax shown above if possible.

**Example output alphabetically:**

Words starting with a:

> and adventure a an (ect.)

**Example output by frequency:**

Words occurring 1 time(s):

> stuff and problems

**An incomplete example of what I'm trying to do:**

```
public string FrecquincyWordBuilder()
{
    string fromatedWords = string.Empty;
    var groups =
        from w in this.myWords
        group w by w.value;
}
```

Comment: As there seems to be some confusion as to what you actually mean, please provide some sample data - a brief example of what data you have, and what you expect the output to look like, rather than adding more explanation *about* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I am using.

```
  public string FrecquincyWordBuilder()
  {

      string fromatedWords = string.Empty;
      this.myWords.SortByFrequency();
      Dictionary<string, int> wordsAndFec = this.myWords.wordsAsDictionary();
      return GroupWordsByFercs(wordsAndFec);


  }

  private static string GroupWordsByFercs(Dictionary<string, int> wordsAndFec)
  {
      String formatedWords = string.Empty;
      var groups =
          from w in wordsAndFec
          group w by w.Value;
      foreach (var group in groups)
      {
          formatedWords += ("\n Words ocurring " + group.Key + " times:\n");
          foreach (var w in group)
          {
              formatedWords += (w.Key + " ");
          }
      }
      return formatedWords;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about the role of the first letter in your question...but this will group by the first letter of each word, then sort the group by occurrences of that word.

```
   var groups =
      from w in this.myWords
      group w by w.Key.First() into g // group by word first letter
      select new { 
            FirstLetter = g.Key, // the group key is the first letter
            WordsWithThisFirstLetter = // order the words with this first letter
                (from wordWithThisFirstLetter in g
                 order by wordWithThisFirstLetter.Value // the number of occurrences of this word
                 select new { 
                         Word = wordWithThisFirstLetter.Key, // dictionary item key 
                         Occurrences = wordWithThisFirstLetter.Value // dictionary item value
                 }
                ).ToArray()

      };
```

Comment: I fairly sure my answers in there but it's doing a bit more then I need and is losing me a little. It only needs to sort by 1st letter or by occurrences not both at the same time.sorry for I misspoke in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, then solution is:

```
var groups = from kv in myWordsDictionary
                         group kv by kv.Key.First() into g
                         orderby g.Key
                         select g;
```

With lambda:

```
var groups = myWordsDictionary.GroupBy(d => d.Key.First()).OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```

GroupBy - group KeyValuePairs by Key first letter.

OrderBy - order groups alphabetically

Comment: When trying the above code (Not lambda) I get a error "Could not find an implantation of query patter for source type ___________ 'GroupBy' not found. Also I misspoke in the original question, which i have fixed. the code doesn't not need to sort on 2 criteria at once.

Comment: @JamesThompson: In my sample myWordsDictionary is Dictionary<string, int>. Can you use something like "myWordsDictionary = this.myWords.WordsAsDictionary()"?

Comment: @JamesThompson: I don't know what exactly is "this.mywords". If WordsAsList returns List<string> then WordsAsDictionary should return Dictionary<string, int>.

Comment: Ok I got it I wan't thinking about it right. But I got it now.